# Showing that $\mathbb{P}(U - V > 0) = \frac{2}{3}$ for dependent Uniform r.v. with given joint DF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Assume $U, V$ to be $Unif[0,1]$ variables with the following joint distribution function $F$:
>
> $$F(u,v)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} u, &0\leq u \leq v/2 \leq 1/2\\
> v/2, & 0 \leq v/2 \leq u < 1 - v/2 \\
> u + v - 1, & 1/2 \leq 1 - v/2 \leq u \leq 1 \end{array} \right.$$
>
> I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{P}( V - U > 0 ) = \frac{2}{3} $

In other words,  $\mathbb{P}(U \leq V) = \frac{2}{3}$.

On a side note, it can be shown that the support of $F$ lies through the following points:  $(0,0)(\frac{1}{2}, 1)(1, 0)$. Since the mass here is assumed to be uniform, the easiest way here is to calculate the mass above $v = u$ line, which results the wanted $\frac{2}{3}$.

**My question:** what would be the *technical* way of evaluating this probability? That is, assuming we don't know how does the support of $F$ look like?

From what I've gathered (please correct me if I'm wrong), one way would be through conditional probabilities, as in

$$ \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(U \leq V) &= \int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{P}( U \leq z | V = z)f_{V}(z)dz \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{P}( U \leq z,  V = z)dz \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_0^{z} \mathbb{P}( U = x,  V = z) dx \right ) dz 
\end{align*}$$

But this does not seem convenient, since the $\mathbb{P}(U = u, V = v)$ expression does not seem trivial to derive from the known $F$ (or is it?).

Could we condition on some other event, allowing for $\{ V \leq z \}$ condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have in mind by saying "...assuming we don't know how does the support of $F$ look like..."

Basically when we are given such a CDF and we see that it's mixed derivative $\partial^2/ \partial u \partial v$ is zero [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), we **WILL** go find out that the density is concentrated on the boundaries of the regions: the two line segments joining the points $(0,0)(\frac{1}{2}, 1)(1, 0)$.

It is not like in a homework that we are just given this fact. In the natural course of solving this problem we deduce that the density is the 2-dim Dirac delta `wall' along the region-boundaries (what you call the support of $F$). This is not cheating or handwaving but the legit approach.

In particular, when you take the 1st derivative of $dF/du$ you will have uniform distributions that take $v$ as a parameter. Formally, uniform distribution consists of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) (or more often in statistics people use the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)).

The 2nd derivative (differentiating a step function) will give you $\delta(\cdot)$ the [Dirac delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html), and BTW the first derivative of the Dirac delta function $\delta'(\cdot)$. Please [consult wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives) or Eq.(10) of the [Wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) to see how $\delta'(\cdot)$ works.

So if you want the ***technical*** way of doing this, first get familiar with taking the step function and its derivatives. Basically this is low level **functional analysis** where you treat the `support' of $F$ still as the entire unit square, and you treat a concentrated mass (be it a point mass in 1-dim, or a line of mass in 2-dim) just the same as any continuous and nicely behaving densities.

If you don't like it, please realize that you still have to face the same "issue" going with the conditional density.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! In this particular case, the support was not given per se, but known from the text. In another SE question of mine a "hint" was suggested to look at the support when showing that $\mathbb{P}(V = 1 - |2U - 1|) = 1$, which seemed to work in this exercise too. So that's where the question is coming from, since it did indeed seem as a trick, rather than common way of approaching this. I'm still uncomfortable working with supports or Dirac delta, since somehow didn't need them in earlier courses, but will dive into it!

Comment: Glad I could have be of help. Yeah Dirac delta is actually more common than you might have realized. Once you get acquainted with it, your view on density functions and their relation with the CDF is going to widen.